# Angular/JavaScript: Can log out the array, but cant log out a single element

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, api, undefined

I spent two hours on i think should be a simple solution thus the html badness. How would i be able to display my tags?
[The html badness](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xc7z0.png)

[The api call i make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6DN1.png)

[The interfaces i put my data into(everything work except the arrays)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzEQO.png)
[The function that calls the api and gets the data that my html needs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2A6sp.png)

Comment: So a few questions:

Is there a reason for not using RxJS?
Is the error on the dev console from the front end trying to access details when it hasn't run yet (async)?

Comment: No images of code please

Answer (score 0):

According to your `PhotoDetails` interface, `tags` is of type `Tag`, not `Tags`. This means that `detail.tags` will return you a single `Tag`. If you want that to be an array your interface should be changed like so:

```
export interface PhotoDetails {
  ...
  tags: Tag[];
  ...
}
```

The `Tags` interface is most likely redundant, and you can get rid of it. When you want an array of `Tag`, just declare the type as `Tag[]`.